# How to create .htaccess to catch html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .htaccess

I have a html page and inside this page I use an audio player which has been created with html , css and javascript and all the files are mp3 ... Everytime When the visitors visit thih page , it needs sometime to load all the files to be ready to play.. it is very slow as the files are long and big  ... the problem is if the visitor refreashes the page or close it and open it .. the loading will start againg!

I want some code or a .htaccess file to catch all the files inside the visitors browser and when they visit it againg ... It shouldn't load all the files againg .

here is my page
https://khamkhor.com/audio/

Thank you very much

Here is my .htaccess  codes

```html
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    #Saves the .mp3 for a week
    <FilesMatch "\.(mp3)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

ExpiresActive on 

ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 60 days" 
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 60 days" 
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 60 days" 
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 60 days" 

ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2 weeks" 
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2 weeks" 

ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType audio/x-wav "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType audio/mpeg "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType audio/mp3 "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType video/mpeg "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType video/quicktime "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType video/x-ms-wmv "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month" 

ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2 weeks" 
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2 weeks" 
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 2 weeks"
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you said yourself, media files are **big**. Caching media content isn't always the best solution. First of all I would suggest that you enable data compression to lower bandwidth requirements on your server as you appear to have none. Here's a guide how to do that https://varvy.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html

This is what a response header from a server using `.gzip` compression looks like with the `content-encoding` header.

[image]

If you do however need to cache media files I would use `mod_headers.c`

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    #Saves the .mp3 for a week
    <FilesMatch "\.(mp3)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Mod headers documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html

Comment: Thank you very much @Victor  ... Should I put the mod_headers.c code inside the .htaccess ?

Comment: Yes @Khamkhor , paste this into your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I added my .htaccess code in the question above .. could you check it now ... Thank you for your help @Victor :)

Comment: It's working. Each downloaded mp3 is cached. This is a screenshot of the network log on your website http://imgur.com/a/yMe0o

Comment: Oops, just realized I forgot to tag you, @Khamkhor there :)